# unable to start debugging in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have Visual studio 2013.From Yesterday, I am unable to run asp.net mvc project bu hitting start button(F5). A dialog box with message "Microsoft visual studio unable to start debugging" prompts.

Things I have tried:

Repair visual studio 2013.

added   "compilation  debug="true"  in web.config.

Could some one please help me.

Comment: What edition and update of Visual Studio 2013 do you have installed?

Comment: Ultimate 2013 Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3